# RLC circuit transfer functions

Tags: transfer-function, passive-networks

[image]I have two parallel RLC circuits with different values. I want to add the transfer function (TF)of both the circuits. If I add Their TF then how to reprenst their equivalent circuit?
[image]

Comment: The transfer function, Vo(s)/Vi(s) of both circuits is 1...  Even if you put them in parallel... Maybe there's something missing.

Comment: The TF of each RLC circuit is unity, assuming you mean TF = Vo(s)/Vi(s). Connecting them in cascade, as implied at the big plus, will give an overall TF of unity.

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in the comments, the transfer function, defined as:
$$ TF(s) = \frac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)}$$
is 1 on both circuits, regardless s.

If you cascade them, it is still 1.

Maybe you meant the admittance of the parallel, defined as:
$$Y(s)=\frac{I_i(s)}{V_i(s)}$$

Then it is the sum of the two admittances. The impedance is its reciprocal.

The parallel equivalent circuit will have a resistor which is the parallel of the two resistors, a capacitor, which is the parallel of the two capacitors, and an inductor which is the parallel of the two inductors. Remmeber what happens when you put in parallel two inductors, two resistors and two capacitors.

Comment: If I have both resistors R1 and R2 in series to parallel  L1, C1 and L2, C2 respectively. In this case we do not have TF unity. In this case can i connect them in cascade to show that it is equivalent to sum of both the TFs?

Comment: If I understood well, now you have two circuits, each one has a R, and then a parallel of L and C. The input is between the resistor terminal (not connected to L-C) and ground, the output is between the node L-C-R and ground (to be sure: it's not the schematics you shown in the question). If you cascade two of these circuits, you can't say that the transfer function is the sum. Not even the product, as the second stage would load the first one.

Comment: Yes you are right. I  have two circuits, each one has a R, and then a parallel of L and C. The input is between the resistor terminal (not connected to L-C) and ground, the output is between the node L-C-R and ground. The transfer function of circuit-1 is H1(S) and transfer function of circuit-2 is H2(S). In my research problem I need to add these two transfer functions (H1(s)+H2(S) and fro that i need to show its equivalent circuit. In case of addition of their transfer functions what would be done on circuit side? any idea?

Comment: Yes you are right. I  have two circuits, each one has a R, and then a parallel of L and C.  The transfer function of circuit-1 is H1(S) and transfer function of circuit-2 is H2(S). In my research problem I need to add these two transfer functions (H1(s)+H2(S) and fro that i need to show its equivalent circuit. In case of addition of their transfer functions what would be done on circuit side? any idea? The image for circuit-1 is added to post. Circuit-2 is similar except for different vales of RLC.

Answer (score 0):

Any combination of any L and any C will store energy, limited by the losses.

Thus L1 will (also) resonant with C2.

Can you tolerate that?

Comment: No that would be a problem if L1 resonate with C2. What about having both resistors R1 and R2 in series to L1, C1 and L2, C2 respectively.